# "cleared from" vs "cleared up from" vs "cleared away from"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I always have problem deciding which one to use.

Example:

> After understanding that, the darkness finally [...] from my
>   eyes.

Should I use *cleared from*, *cleared up from*, or *cleared away from*?

Comment: Fog, haze, and other (some figurative, like confusion) things that obstruct one's vision can clear, but does darkness *clear*? I think darkness *lifts*.

Comment: @Susan I really was just about to type "That's just semantics" and I stopped myself.  LOL!!!!!  I would agree that darkness lifts from ones eyes.  But, I don't think it makes clear wrong, *per se*.

Comment: Consider also editing in the phrase: *After understanding that, the mist/haze finally [...] from my eyes* Two birds with one stone, so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you can use either *cleared from* or *cleared away from* here.

They are fairly interchangeable.

That said, some might argue that *cleared from* implies that the darkness dissolved on its own into nothing.  And, *cleared away from* implies that the darkness moved away from your eyes, but is still present in the universe somewhere.  (I suggest looking between your couch cushions.)

*Cleared up from* means a condition improved (*e.g.* your acne cleared up).

I will source/disclaim all of these answers as being per my ear as a native speaker of American English.

Comment: I would not use either of them for darkness, and endorse what @Susan has said above. But I agree with what you said about acne.  If a tree blows down in the wind (as many did in Manchester on Wednesday) someone has to 'clear away' the debris.

Comment: @WS2 I will not argue that I prefer lift.  I do.  But, I was staying within the context of the OP's question.  See my comment to Susan above.

Answer (score 1):

If we look up the meaning of *clear* in Google dictionary it says: *brighten (up), lighten, clear up, become bright/brighter, become light/lighter, become sunny*. Therefore, as a verb it is more than suitable to use in concomitance with the noun, darkness. Nevertheless, as Susan mentioned in the comments, "[darkness lifted](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&espv=210&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=bks&q=%22darkness+lifted%22&oq=%22darkness+lifted%22&gs_l=serp.12...3141.4039.0.6012.5.5.0.0.0.0.118.455.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.35.serp..4.1.118.tmVePC_SKk0)" is by far the most familiar expression, so one is left with the dilemma of choosing a well-known expression for one much less so.  Only the author can make this final decision.
 Onto some statistics: "Cleared from" in Google books achieved only 371 results.

> Presently the darkness [cleared from](http://books.google.it/books?id=uUEiWZo6XisC&pg=PA98&dq=%22darkness%20cleared%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wuL9UsGdG8O9ygO4hoHABQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22darkness%20cleared%22&f=false) his mind and he opened his eyes

To *[clear away](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clear+away)* means to remove from sight, as in to *clear the table away*.
 Google books yielded a respectable 3,440 results for "darkness cleared away".

> As the [darkness cleared away](http://books.google.it/books?id=UEBdEPXVjQ0C&pg=PA18&dq=%22darkness%20cleared%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wuL9UsGdG8O9ygO4hoHABQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22darkness%20cleared%22&f=false), Selena was able to focus and identify
>   the appearance of a small child

To *[clear up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clear+up)*, a phrasal verb which is often used when something untidy or messy needs clearing. It can also mean to clarify, explain or resolve a mystery, an enigma, or a misunderstanding. *The weather cleared up*, means that it was cloudy and possibly it was going to rain but now the sky is clear.
Google books yielded, astonishingly, a mere 34 results.

> When the long [darkness cleared up](http://books.google.it/books?id=eEITAAAAMAAJ&q=%22darkness%20cleared%20up%22&dq=%22darkness%20cleared%20up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S-T9UtCPH4G7ygPr-4KYBQ&redir_esc=y) he found himself lying on a cot in a
>   strange room.

If I were asked which one to choose, I would opt for "cleared (from). The resulting phrase sounds natural and I would have no difficulty in understanding the author's intent.

> After understanding that, the darkness finally **cleared** from my eyes.